# Variable for store locale in email templates? Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, transactional-mail

Is there a way I can differentiate between different store locales in an email template created in transactional emails section of admin?

I need to point to a different store logo on an international store and including the locale in the image url seems like the most straight-forward way to achieve this.

Comment: are you looking diffrent logo based on store?

Comment: I am trying to change the Logo yes.

Comment: If you uploaded logo store wise from admin, then it autometically set in email template it self.